# Duplicate fields in renamed classes (ASM + Jar)

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

For a project I'm working on I'm trying to rename classes inside a jar file using ASM. I've got it working... but there's a catch. Each class that is renamed in the jar has it's fields duplicated.

Here's my code:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.Remapper;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.RemappingClassAdapter;
import org.objectweb.asm.commons.SimpleRemapper;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
//Imports showing which ASM (5.0.4) classes I'm using

private static void doStuff() throws IOException {
    File jar = new File("Input.jar");
    //Get's the ClassNodes for each class in a jar
    ArrayList<ClassNode> nodes = BCU.loadClasses(jar);
    //Appends '_Test' to each class except for the main class.
    Remapper mapper = new SimpleRemapper(getRename(nodes));
    //Loop through the ClassNodes updating references to renamed classes
    for (ClassNode cn : nodes) {
         ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(BCU.getNodeBytes(cn));
         ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS); 
         RemappingClassAdapter rca = new RemappingClassAdapter(cw, mapper); 
         cr.accept(rca, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES); 
         cr = new ClassReader(cw.toByteArray()); 
         cr.accept(cn,ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
    }
    //Export the nodes as a new jar file and copy over the META-INF folder
    BCU.saveAsJar(nodes, "Output.jar");
}
```

Example output:

```
public static String VERSION;
public static final ConfigFile config;
public static String VERSION;
public static final ConfigFile_Test config;
```

---

**Edit (3/28/2016)**: Coming back after learning more about ASM here's how it should be done:

```
for (ClassNode cn : nodes.values()) {
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
    //mapper is a Remapper instance
    ClassVisitor remapper = new RemappingClassAdapter(cw, mapper);
    cn.accept(remapper);
    //out = Map<String, byte[]>
    out.put(renamed.get(cn.name).getRenamed(), cw.toByteArray());
}
```

Antimony was right. My original idea back when I posted this was to edit the ClassNode itself *(I had a ClassNode extension that handled everything. It was pretty nasty)*. Since moving to the Remapper implementation things have been working much better.

Comment: Well, and what do you want?

Comment: Where's the assembly code?  I only see Java.  Did you mean to use the java-bytecode-asm tag instead?

Comment: @PeterSmith Fixed the tag. I forgot ASM would expand into Assembly.
@ Andremoniy I'm attempting to rename class files in a jar file. The renaming part works, but all of the fields are duplicated in the process. This makes the jar file unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cr.accept(cn,ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
```

The problem is that you're calling accept on an existing ClassNode. ClassNode.visitField *adds* a field to the class node. So everything in the ClassNode is doubled - one copy from the existing data and one copy that you added.

Comment: Thanks, I made a cheap workaround by making a class that extends ClassNode to prevent duplicate entries.